# Spring application shut down at startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, startup

I have this strange behaviour with my spring boot application where suddently the startup process doesn't work anymore. Here's the all the log:
[image]
I really can't say what's wrong since it stopped working. I also fetched on `git` the remote version of the code that is deployed and working right now. I use `Intellij Idea` as IDE, I have already restarted the IDE and the laptop.
I looked over the Internet but everyone having this issue has problems abot pom or dependency. I can't get a clue from the logs. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>it.reag</groupId>
        <artifactId>reag-common-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>reag-mailsender-batch</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.reag</groupId>
            <artifactId>reag-common-api-model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>MailSenderBatch</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Note that if I change the `spring-boot-starter` dependency with `spring-boot-starter-web` the app works, but I don't understand why. I don't use any of the feature of web environment. Also, it worked perfectly until the other day with the `spring-boot-starter` dependency.

Comment: The name of the application is MailSender, to send an mail is an process of an defined start (the begin of the sending) and a defined end (the successfull transportation of a mail). The faster the process ends the more efficient is the application. What is your expectation here? Do you need a button labeled "Send now"? Since the Context is a "AnnotationConfigApplicationContext" but not a "AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext" I do not think a button "send now" will be available.

Comment: I don't need a "Send button". The application sends an email at startup without needing a web context. I don't see your point.

Comment: Maybe is silly but did you check if there are any difference between your code and the stable version?
Are you logging everything? check the log level and check if all the parameters that this application needs to start are provided..

The question should be more like "where do I start to check when my application stop working" because you are not providing too much information about your issue.

Comment: I think the point of @PeterRader  is that from the type of ApplicationContext that you are using seems like that the application is doing his job, is terminating maybe because the job is done.

Comment: Do you have the `org.springframework.boot : spring-boot-starter-web` dependency included?

Comment: Please add your POM.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this answer as it may help others. If one defines a parent in pom like you have here:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>it.reag</groupId>
        <artifactId>reag-common-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

Then a simple dependency of spring-boot-starter-web in this module pom may not be the same as you expected, it may be customized in parent, aka reag-common-api pom, servlet container may be removed there. This happens because of dependency hierachy rule in maven. In this way, in order to verify that a missing container is the reason why spring application starts and quits, one can use `mvn dependency:tree` to see if a tomcat or undertow or netty is shown as a container (not an exact expression).

In my project, this would be neede for submodule pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

As its parent has this:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```